# cannot use again my magento site

Tags: frontend

I cannot use my frontend site on a pc browser.
I will get only a grey site and cannot click any Link.
Hope somebody can help me there.
kindly regards for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a defect css file.
kindly regards